# What is the reason if(arr[i] < arr[j+1]) return false?

Tags: java

I know it is not the best approach to sort an array but what is the reason **if(arr[i] < arr[j+1])** return false.
It should return true because in first loop **if(5<4)** and so on is true

```
int arr[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    for(int i = 0,p = 4; i< 4; i++, p--){
        for(int j = i; j < 4; j++){
            if(!(arr[i] < arr[j+1])){

                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i : arr)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: do you know what that ! does to your condition?

Comment: You don't have `if(arr[i] < arr[j+1])` in your code.  You have `if(!(arr[i] < arr[j+1]))`

Comment: Not related but variable ```p``` is never used. The condition ```i < 4``` is incorrect  since it will not reach the last element of the array.

Comment: @Mark The last element is actually reached by `j+1`. But the `p` is unused, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!(arr[i] < arr[j+1])
```

This says

> if arr at index i is NOT smaller than array at index j+1.

Your logic is backwards.

Comment: Always happy to help!